# Setting an Azure Webhook authLevel to anonymous

Tags: azure, azure-functions, api-key

I'd like to be able to call my Azure function without having to specify a key. The [documentation seems to indicate that setting the 'authLevel' to anonymous accomplishes this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook):

> authLevel : This determines what keys, if any, need to be present on
>   the request in order to invoke the function. See Working with keys
>   below. The value can be one of the following:
>
> - anonymous: No API key is required.
> - function: A function-specific API key is required. This is the default value if none is provided.
> - admin : The master key is required.

My binding is:

```
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "webHookType": "genericJson",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
```

Yet, when I send a request to the function without a key I receive the error:

> The WebHook verification request must contain a 'code' query parameter.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: From the same document you are referencing, there is another link for "Working with keys":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#keys

Scroll to "Keys and webhooks".  It states that you will need to provide a key.

Comment: Thanks, I should have heeded the text in that section: "Each mechanism does, however rely on a key". I was a bit confused between this and the documentation for the webHookType.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chris, 
`authLevel` does not apply to WebHooks as the authentication there is completely handled by the WebHook receiver you select (e.g. Slack, Generic JSON, Salesforce, etc.), you'll notice that option is disabled in the UI.

I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/143) to enhance the documentation with this information.

If you need an anonymous WebHook to take a JSON payload, the alternative is to use an HTTP Trigger function, set the `authLevel` to anonymous and either handle the request directly or bind to a string, JObject or a POCO.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed in the webHookType property it explicitly mentioned authLevel for github and slack. It was not mentioned for genericJson, which made think it could be set for that type.

Comment: @Fabio are WebHooks implemented with Azure Functions under the covers?

Comment: I may need some clarification on the question, but the WebHooks implementation in Azure Functions relies on the ASP.NET WebHooks feature, so we leverage their receivers and inherit the functionality they expose. This is all hosted and managed by Azure Functions. Does that answer the question?