# Can Azure Function runtime/webhooks services be set to allow anonymous?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

many extensions have started to populate the /runtime/webhooks subpath with services (signalr & durable functions as examples).  But they seem to always require a host key, but since my functions are behind easy auth we long ago stopped using the host key driven authentication and set everything to anonymous and rely on the easy auth security proxy and MS identity driven bearer token auth to access our functions.  It works great...however clients aren't able to consume the /runtime/webhooks stuff which seems to still require a key.

I have considered setting a dummy key, but would prefer to just switch all/some of the runtime webhooks to anonymous.  Is this possible?

I'm under the impression that the /runtime/webhooks stuff leveraged by extensions is different than the webhook bindings as talked about [Setting an Azure Webhook authLevel to anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622400/setting-an-azure-webhook-authlevel-to-anonymous) but i certainly could be mistaken and they may be the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting an Azure Webhook authLevel to anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622400/setting-an-azure-webhook-authlevel-to-anonymous)

Comment: i don't think that applies because that's the webhook binding, the runtime/webhooks is a different beast entirely AFAIK